# Which one to use between IList<T> and List<T>

Tags: list, ilist

I have list of emplyoees, then which one I should use between IList and List and why? I am using C#.

In which scenario I use List and IList.

Thank you.

Comment: Use IList in c#, List in java

Comment: Thank you. But my doubt is why should I use IList instaed of List?

Comment: You should give us some more details (programming language, where do you use the list, ...). Generelly you should use interfaces so you can substitute implementation without changing usages.

Comment: Which language you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IList represent a non-generic collection for collection of objects. If you use IList you can create customized `List`s and use advantages of [DIP (Dependency Inversion Principle)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) of OOP.

```
SimpleList<T> : IList<T>
{
    ...
} 

IList<T> list1 = new List<T>();
IList<T> list2 = new SimpleList<T>();
```

You behave same with these two kind of lists.